# JS Ajax: local vs absolute path issue when using SEO friendly urls

Tags: javascript, ajax, apache, .htaccess

here's the thing:

i built my site with SEO friendly urls...but i have problem now calling ajax files becaus eth epath is wrong and I cant set an absolute url when i call my files in background..

for instance my page is here (similar to StackOverflow..)

```
www.domain.com/product/123/this-is-a-product
```

but my javascripts functions, in folder `/js`,now they try to reach the files but they cant obvisouly because are set to relative path...

how can i solve this issue??

EDIT: Found this [How to get the root path in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465954/how-to-get-the-root-path-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using freindly urls, then you have to use path started with /. But then you are starting path from main path.

Comment: Not, i meat slash at the beggining with out the dot, cause if you wont use it and have some line to view.php on site domain.com/view/32 it will give you domain.com/view/32/view.php so you have to use slash at beggining to reduce that /view/32. And you have to use it on <A> only :D

Comment: Simply ensure that all your ajax requests go to a target that starts / e.g. /path.xml . That will ensure the request goes to http://www.domain.com/path.xml .